# SQL/Impala: dynamically determine the latest month interval

Tags: sql, impala

I am using the following code to find the last month data:

```
select * from table1 where timestamp > "2016-07-14 00:00:00"
```

---

"2016-07-14 00:00:00"  is manually picked as the date one month prior to today. However, I don't want to change the date "2016-07-14 00:00:00" each time I ran it, so I am wondering is there some kind of date function I can use to achieve this goal? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DATEADD()`:

`SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE timestamp > DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())`

Docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186819.aspx

Comment: I tried above, but get this error: HiveServer2Error: AnalysisException: Could not resolve column/field reference: 'month'

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Impala has its own built-in function:
http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/impala/2-x/2-1-x/topics/impala_datetime_functions.html

I found the query below works:

```
select * from table1 where timestamp > add_months(now(), -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression `now() - interval 1 month` gives you a timestamp for one month ago:

```
[localhost:21000] > select now() - interval 1 month;
+-------------------------------+
| now() - interval 1 month      |
+-------------------------------+
| 2016-07-31 17:14:09.086188000 |
+-------------------------------+
```

Using `trunc(..., 'DD')` you can round it the beginning of the day:

```
[localhost:21000] > select trunc(now() - interval 1 month, 'DD');
+---------------------------------------+
| trunc(now() - interval 1 month, 'dd') |
+---------------------------------------+
| 2016-07-31 00:00:00                   |
+---------------------------------------+
```

So your query could like this, for example:

```
select * from table1 where timestamp > trunc(now() - interval 1 month, 'DD');
```

You can find more details about these and other date and time functions at http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/impala/2-x/2-1-x/topics/impala_datetime_functions.html